# Versions of libraries included in the JDK

Tags: java

I just ran into a problem with the version of JAX-WS in JDK 1.6.0 being different than the one in JDK 1.6.0_14.

I've been searching around for a list of the various libraries that are packaged in the JDK that shows the versions of the library included in the version of the JDK.

I haven't had any luck yet.

Is there such a list?

Comment: In the specific case of JAX-WS (which is a special case!), the API version changed in, IIRC, 6u4 and 6u14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this information can be found by digging around in the JavaDocs for the release (not the API docs, but the release notes and spec notes (e.g. for [Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/) ). It's in there somewhere, but sometimes that kind of info is tricky to find.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably in JSR 270 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=270) which defines exactly what is Java6. But I havent checked and JSR are not the most pleasant readings ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking inside the jar file?

In the META-INF folder is a file called manifest.xml which might contain version information. Some vendors do this (e.g. Oracle's JDBC driver has this), but some don't.